# What does the symbol for pi with a lower perpendicular mean?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, k-nearest-neighbour, notation

What does [image] mean in context of the equation [image]

Comment: It denotes the Indicator Function https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function, in your example it returns 1 when $y_i$ equals $y$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: ... with the LaTex code `\mathbb{I}` giving $\mathbb{I}$  rather than `\pi` giving $\pi$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [indicator function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) $\mathbb{I}(y_i =y)$ takes the value 1 when $y_i =y$ and takes the value 0 otherwise.

It's not a $\Pi$ symbol: you can typeset it using blackboard style: `\mathbb{I}`.